# Sheva Brachos when getting divorced

Tags: halacha, blessing, divorce, sheva-brachos

If for whatever reason it was decided that a couple would get married then right away get divorced after the week of Sheva Brachos (believe it or not this happens!) Can they indeed still make Sheva Brachos during the week after the Chassanah? Is there any reason why if they have decided to get divorce and terminate the marriage after these days that the actual "Sheva Brachos" can't be made?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Here's an example of a Rav who talks about the severity of breaking an engagement: http://revach.net/halacha/tshuvos/Rav-Moshe-Shternbuch-When-An-Engagement-Is-Broken/3001 -- There are indeed certain groups who will marry and divorce rather than break of the engagement (I read about it a while ago and can't remember the exact details). That being said, they probably don't throw a huge bash

Comment: @MonicaCellio Good question, that apparently that's what some people do since they say it's better to get married and get divorced rather than call of the shidduch. I heard this quoted in a name the Vilna Gaon. I don't know what the source is though and perhaps someone else even said it.

Comment: You can read about the "Cherem Hakadmonim" regarding breaking an engagement here (if it applies today, etc.) in the Nitei Gavriel: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46551&pgnum=400

Comment: I've heard of a couple that divorced the day after. I guess they really were seeking a "one night stand". Oh - you can imagine what occurred 9 months later. What a mess!

Answer (score 2):

The question wording is actually inaccurate, Halachically speaking - `make Sheva Brachos during the week after the Chassanah`.

While common practise it to "make Sheva Brachos", Halachically, Sheva Brachos are said at meals after the wedding under specific conditions.

See the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [Siman 149](http://www.kitzur.net/main.php?siman=149) for details.

Essentially, in the case of 2 people who have never been married, then if there are Panim Chadashot - and it's not only close family at the meal, then Sheva Brachos are said.

Going back to your question, if they plan on getting divorced, they probably are not going to even be eating together. But if they do - and there are Panim Chadashot present - then they are obligated to add *The Sheva Brachos* after Birkat HaMazon.

Comment: The question was whether the pending divorce affects anything. (This seems like a poor question as it asks users to prove the negative, and provides no reason why it should make a difference). Nevertheless, this doesn't seem to add anything to the question, other than your baseless assumption that a pending divorce doesn't affect anything. || Whether the OP meant make a designated meal, as you understood, or whether he literally meant making the 7 blessings, this remains an undemonstrated assumption.

Comment: I wonder if the meal can be considered לכבוד the wedding and if the guests can be considered מרבים שמחה if the whole thing is a farce and no one is happy. Arguably then the blessings can't be said even if new people happen to be eating near the "couple" (like how we don't add even the one ברכת חתנים when eating just with בני ביתו)